# Overriding superclass method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass

Class A.h

```
@protocol ClassADelegate;

@interface ClassA : UIView
    // Some properties

- (void)setupModalView;
@end

@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>
    // Some delegate methos
@end
```

Class A.m

```
- (void)setupModalView{
    // Some code
}
```

So, I created a subclass of my class "A," and called it "B."

B.h

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA

@end
```

So, on `B.m` I want to override `setupModalView` method from my class "A." I did this:

B.m

```
- (void)setupModalView{
    NSLog(@"Done.");
}
```

I think it should work, however it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? (To clarify: I want `setupModalView` on class B to do something completely different from `setupModalView` on class A).

**Edit**: I'm instantiating ClassB like this:

```
 ClassB *classB = ({
        [[ClassB alloc]initWithNotification:nil]; // Notification is a custom NSObject... nvm
    });

    classB.delegate = self;
    [classB show];
```

**Edit 2**: Here's my init methods for ClassA:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNotification:(Notification *)notification{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [[ClassA alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [self configureDetailView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work. The instantiation and method call in particular.

Comment: @Zaph see updated question. The 'show' just puts the UIView on screen. 'setupModalView' gets called in my custom 'initWithNotification:' method.

Comment: You need to show the implementation of your init methods. Subclassing isn't broken, and none of the code in your current question is wrong.

Comment: @jrturton I added my init methods to the question.

Comment: What are you doing there in `ClassA`'s `init` method? And what's `EMMessageDetailView`? What's its relationship to `ClassA`? Also why are you surrounding your instantiations with `({`?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Ok, modified it a little bit. Mi `init` method con `ClassA` is as is here... `EMMessageDetailView` was the real name of "`ClassA`," and my instantiations are like that for no reason at all.

Comment: Kudos on your use of `instancetype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self = [[ClassA alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

This is wrong. You've already assigned self, now you're explicitly making it an instance of ClassA. If initWithFrame is your designated initialiser, then you need to call it instead of `[super init]` when you originally assign something to self.

Never use an explicit class name in an initialiser - that will make your class unsubclassable.

Instead of `[super init]`, you need to write `[self initWithFrame...`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense... don't know what I was thinking about. Let me refactor some things.

Comment: This solved my problem. Now I can subclass ClassA without a problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@protocol ClassADelegate;
@interface ClassA : UIView
- (void)setupModalView;
@end
@implementation ClassA
- (void)setupModalView {
    NSLog(@"Super..");
}
@end

@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>
- (void)SomeDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end
@implementation ClassB
- (void)setupModalView {
    NSLog(@"Done.");
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[ClassB new] setupModalView];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

NSLog output
2013-09-26 23:03:12.817 Test[41586:a0b] Done.